# Android (newbie) image/s layout/scaling problem

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a total noob so I might have gotten the basics wrong but this is just confusing the heck out of me.

I have one image button and one background image here
(note: bikini girl so might be NSFW - I figured if i was going to be seeing this screen for a long time i might as well have something interesting there ;D )

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/finaldi.jpg/

As you can see at different screen sizes the background image scales fine, but my image button at first has a weird border around it and then it just starts shrinking.

I have made the same image button in 36x36,48x48,72x72 and 96x96 and put them in the 
drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi directories without any change :(

How can I get that button to be the same on all screens?
I was reading on DIP but where do i declare that?

Thanks!

EDIT, The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/background_ass">
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/level1" 
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
                android:onClick="button_clicked1"
                android:background="#00000000"  android:layout_width="48dip" android:layout_height="48dip">
            </ImageButton>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik the ImageButton has a minimal size, that's the visible border. You can get rid of it by defining a transparent background and zero padding:

```
<ImageButton ... background="#00000000" padding="0px"/>
```

update after having the code:
The problem here is that the width and height of the ImageButton are fixed and the image is not told to scale.

[The SDK docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) give some explanation about handling multiple screen sizes/resolutions, but it's not a trivial issue!
My recommendation would be, depending on your needs:

- If the relative size (dip) should be exactly the same on all devices, add *scaleType="fitXY"* to the declaration of the ImageButton
- If it's ok to have the size slighly change, set layout_width and layout_height to "wrap_content".

Comment: Ok, padding didnt change much.. upvoted your answer. Am thinking of trying "density independent pixels (dip)" but dont know where to enter the values... any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I just created more buttons and am using that but will select your answer as I used the background transparent code and you tried your best to help. Thanks!